# An error occurs in the Altbeacon scan function. When using Android API version 30 or higher

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

According to the Google Play Market distribution standard,
developing using Android API target version 30 or higher.

When trying to use the Altbeacon scan function, the error below occurs.

`error :  Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles. at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382) at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:673) at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:660) at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.getWakeUpOperation(CycledLeScanner.java:529) at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.cancelWakeUpAlarm(CycledLeScanner.java:541) at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.setScanPeriods(CycledLeScanner.java:192) at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob.restartScanning(ScanJob.java:267) at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob.startScanning(ScanJob.java:312) at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob.access$600(ScanJob.java:43) at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob$1.run(ScanJob.java:110)`

Mobile device model and OS version
ANDROID Galaxy S10E

Android Beacon Library version
android-beacon-library-2.17.1.

For Android version 30 or lower, the beacon scan function works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/1043) and is in release 2.19+.  Please upgrade to that library version to resolve this problem.

Comment: Thank you. There was a mistake that I couldn't confirm in the documentation.